# Overwrite Array Values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Consider the array variable below...

```
var fruits = [];
fruits.push("banana");
fruits.push("apple");
fruits.push("mango");
fruits.push("orange");
fruits.push("grapes");
```

We should have these values...

```
fruits[0]=>"banana"
fruits[1]=>"apple"
fruits[2]=>"mango"
fruits[3]=>"orange"
fruits[4]=>"grapes"
```

Say I have a pointer and it's currently at number `2`, so the current value is `mango`, how do I overwrite `orange` and `grapes` when I do another `push`? Is it possible? Say I wanted to add `coconut` but I don't want it assigned to `fruits[5]`, what I would like to have is `orange` getting replaced with `coconut` and it goes on and on... How do I achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: you are looking for `.splice()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
fruits.splice(3, 1, 'coconut')
```

The arguments are:

1. start at index
2. delete count
3. replace with (optional)

Answer (score 2):

Use assignment to replace an item at one index:

```
fruits[3] = 'coconut';
```

...or if you don't know where it is:

```
fruits[fruits.indexOf('orange')] = 'coconut';
```

Alternatively, if you want to do a replacement with a predicate:

```
fruits = fruits.map(f => f === 'orange' ? 'coconut' : f);
```

...or use splice like @inorganik recommended if you want to do more advanced things like replacing a range of indexes with 0 or more replacements.

Lots of options. MDN is a great resource if you have a data type and want to see all the operations available. Here's some [`Array` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 1):

There's already a good answer of using `splice`, I do not mean to disrespect it. 
However, **splice** is a method that mutates an existing array. Personally I'd prefer of using `slice` instead:

```
const newFruits = fruits.slice(0, end).concat(values);
```

Where **end** stands for the "pointer" mentioned in the question. And **values** represent *an array* of values to be added (like `['coconut']`).

Answer (score 1):

You could even define your own "psh()" function to start inserting at an arbitrary position like this:

```js
fruits=["banana","apple","mango","orange","grapes"];
function defpsh(arr,i){arr.psh=function(v){ this[i++]=v }}

defpsh(fruits,2); // start "pshing"at offset 2

fruits.psh('coconut');
fruits.psh('lemon');

console.log(fruits);
```